# Sublime Text 2 Ctrl+P doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Why Sublime Text  2 Ctrl+P doesn't work on some projects while it works on other projects?

Thanks for skuroda's tips, the log in console after hitting ctrl+p is as folows:

```
command: show_overlay {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true}
Unable to auto detect encoding, using fallback encoding Western (Windows 1252)
Unable to auto detect encoding, using fallback encoding Western (Windows 1252)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 175, in on_load
    callback.__module__, "on_load", EVENT_TIMEOUT)
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 154, in run_timed_function
    ret = f()
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 174, in <lambda>
    run_timed_function(lambda: callback.on_load(v),
  File ".\sublime_gbk.py", line 51, in on_load
  File ".\sublime_gbk.py", line 36, in gbk2utf8
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Window.focus_view(Window, NoneType)
did not match C++ signature:
    focus_view(class SP<struct edit_window::reference>, class SP<class TextBufferView>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 175, in on_load
    callback.__module__, "on_load", EVENT_TIMEOUT)
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 154, in run_timed_function
    ret = f()
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 174, in <lambda>
    run_timed_function(lambda: callback.on_load(v),
  File ".\sublime_gbk.py", line 51, in on_load
  File ".\sublime_gbk.py", line 36, in gbk2utf8
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Window.focus_view(Window, NoneType)
did not match C++ signature:
    focus_view(class SP<struct edit_window::reference>, class SP<class TextBufferView>)
```

Comment: Probably your p key is defected. Or ctrl. Or you should be sure they are projects.

Comment: It's a little bit strange! It should work even when there is no file opened!

Comment: Try disabling sublime-gbk plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to offer any additional help without more information. With that being said, try opening on the console `ctrl+backtick` or `View -> Show Console`. In there enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`. Every time you hit `ctrl+p`, it should print something like `command: show_overlay {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true}`
. If it doesn't please specify what it does say. In addition, you can verify the input ST is receiving by entering `sublime.log_input(True)` in the console. This should always return something like `key evt: control+p`.

Hopefully with those two commands you can provide some additional information. I'll edit my answer appropriately if/when you update.

Edit:

It looks like a plugin is causing issues. I'm guessing it's [sublime-gbk](https://github.com/akira-cn/sublime-gbk), but I'm just guessing. You can try creating an issue on the developer's page and hope it gets addressed. The only thing I could advise is disabling the plugin. You could try modifying the plugin also. This may break something, but in `def gbk2utf8(view):`, you can do something like

```
if view is None:
    return
```

before the try except block. Of course, aligning the spacing as necessary so it's valid Python.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It looks like a plugin issue, so there isn't much I can do.