# Why would the Ctrl+p keybinding for Goto Anywhere stop working in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

All of a sudden `ctrl+p` doesn't do anything anymore, regardless of whether I'm in a project or not. I don't get any errors as with [Sublime Text 2 Ctrl+P doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17838057/183350), although before restarting Sublime Text I was getting a dialog box with a bunch of debugging info.

Answer (score 1):

If the suggestions in [Sublime Text 2 Ctrl+P doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17838057/183350) don't help you, maybe you installed a package that hijacks the keybinding, such as [2pdf](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/2pdf), which is very easy to accidentally install via Package Control because it's the first alphabetical listing :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same with you,  but when I check my key bindings, I found the goto cmd is set to other keys like that:

```
{ "keys": ["super+t"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} },
{ "keys": ["super+p"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} },
```

so you can just check it.